# Why is JQuery .load() getting fired twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner in web development, I've tried multiple things and nothing works.
I have the following button in my index.html

```
<button  id="login" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" onclick="test()"> Login </button>
```

index.js

```
$(document).ready($(function () {

function initMenu() {
console.log('mainmenu.html --->' );
}
function test() {
    console.log('Hello');
    $(".container").load("mainmenu.html", function () {
        initMenu();
    });
});
}
```

the function initMenu() gets called twice as shown in the picture below, why is this happening?

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fypxT.png)

Comment: `$(document).ready($(function () {` should be `jQuery(function($) {`

Comment: `console.log(mainmenu.html ---> );` should be `console.log("mainmenu.html --->");`

Comment: Don't use inline JS handlers like `onclick` JS should not be disseminated inside HTML documents. Use `.addEventListener()` instead. Or rather `$("#login").on("click", function(ev) {` since you already use jQuery.

Comment: Is your `<button>` inside a `<form>`, or?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan the console.log string without "" is a typo.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan no, the <button> is not inside a <form>

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't understand your code. I think it has lots of problem so that I can't execute. I think the right code should be like this:

```
<body>
        <button id="login" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"> Login </button>
        <div class="container"></div>
    </body>
    <script src="2/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            function initMenu() {
                console.log('mainmenu.html-- - >');
            }

            $('#login').click(function() {
                    console.log('Hello');
                    $(".container").load("mainmenu.html", function() {
                        initMenu();
                    });
                });
        });
    </script>
```